How can I add padding between a header and the previous and immediate lines in org mode
How can I add padding between a header and its adjacent lines so that they look cleanly formatted like any Rich Text Editor does.
I was able to use a workaround using the :box face-attribute to do something close.
:box `(:line-width (12 . 8)
       :color ,(plist-get customFaceData :background)
       :style flat-button)

For example

this screenshot is before applying box and
this screenshot is after applying box XX

But even after this change I still would like to see some more gap between the text and the header - like highlighted in this desired output screenshot - highlighted
In this screenshot I made sure to add an empty line after and before each header.
NOTE: Please note that I'm looking for a way without using the :box
Desired Output screenshot:


Add a newline or two manually.

yes, that what I did in the desired screenshot without any highlights. Curious to know if there's any way to configure emacs to make it look like this without adding a newline. And TBH, I think I only need 1/2 a line gap at the top and bottom
